# NPM Packages need fundings

Tags: web3js, truffle, npm

I'm installing some developer tools on Mac to work on some bigger projects but some of the packages need funding. What does that mean and how do I fund them?

```
KALEBS-MacBook-Pro:~ root# npm install truffle -g
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)

changed 144 packages, and audited 145 packages in 14s

37 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Comment: Did you run `npm fund` for details..?

Comment: Yes, but what do I do after that?

Comment: Okay, to be clear - you've successfully installed the packages, you're now free to use them as you wish. The 'npm fund' functionality is a way for package owners to ask users to voluntarily contribute money to help fund more work on the package. You can either ignore it, or send them some money if you wish to help the project.